# Request Timeouts when viewing Site Pages

Tags: 2013, time-out, sitepages

Since installing the March 2015 CUs on our environment, we're periodically running into an issue where users accessing one of our web applications encounter errors trying to access their sites.

I've managed to narrow it down to users specifically trying to access pages stored in the Site Pages library. Accessing default.aspx, or any of other system pages or lists directly works without issue. If I perform a recycle of the application pool hosting the web app, then things begin working normally again for a few days, and then it randomly craps out again.

Here's the relevant ULS logs when trying to access one of the pages:

> 07/29/2015 11:12:12.37    w3wp.exe (0x23D4)   0x1F44  SharePoint
>   Foundation    Logging Correlation Data    xmnv    Medium  Name=Request
>   (GET:http://mywebapp.com/sites/somesite/SitePages/Home.aspx)  2bcc1e9d-888d-80ef-0089-f88bde0ba113
>   07/29/2015 11:12:12.37    w3wp.exe (0x23D4)   0x1F44  SharePoint
>   Foundation    Authentication Authorization    agb9s   Medium  Non-OAuth
>   request. IsAuthenticated=True, UserIdentityName=0#.w|domain\username,
>   ClaimsCount=125   2bcc1e9d-888d-80ef-0089-f88bde0ba113 07/29/2015
>   11:12:12.39   w3wp.exe (0x23D4)   0x1F44  SharePoint
>   Foundation    Files   ak8dj   High    UserAgent not available, file operations
>   may not be optimized.    at
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.SPFileStreamManager.CreateCobaltStreamContainer(SPFileStreamStore
>   spfs, ILockBytes ilb, Boolean copyOnFirstWrite, Boolean disposeIlb)
>   at
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.SPFileStreamManager.SetInputLockBytes(SPFileInfo&
>   fileInfo, SqlSession session, PrefetchResult prefetchResult)     at
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.CoordinatedStreamBuffer.SPCoordinatedStreamBufferFactory.CreateFromDocumentRowset(Guid
>   databaseId, SqlSession session, SPFileStreamManager spfstm, Object[]
>   metadataRow, SPRowset contentRowset, SPDocumentBindRequest& dbreq,
>   SPDocumentBindResults& dbres)     at
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.SPSqlClient.GetDocumentContentRow(Int32 rowOrd,
>   Object ospFileStmMgr, SPDocumentBindRequest& dbreq,
>   SPDocumentBindResults& dbres)     at
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.Library.SPRequestInternalClass.GetFileAndMetaInfo(String
>   bstrUrl, Byte bPageView, Byte bPageMode, Byte bGetBuildDependencySet,
>   String bstrCurrentFolderUrl, Int32 iRequestVersion, Byte
>   bMainFileRequest, Boolean& pbCanCustomizePages, Boolean&
>   pbCanPersonalizeWebParts, Boolean& pbCanAddDeleteWebParts, Boolean&
>   pbGhostedDocument, Boolean& pbDefaultToPersonal, Boolean&
>   pbIsWebWelcomePage, String& pbstrSiteRoot, Guid& pgSiteId, UInt32&
>   pdwVersion, String& pbstrTimeLastModified, String& pbstrContent,
>   UInt32& pdwPartCount, Object& pvarMetaData, Object&
>   pvarMultipleMeetingDoclibRootFolders, String& pbstrRedirectUrl,
>   Boolean& pbObjectIsList, Guid& pgListId, UInt32& pdwItemId, Int64&
>   pllListFlags, Boolean& pbAccessDenied, Guid& pgDocid, Byte& piLevel,
>   UInt64& ppermMask, Object& pvarBuildDependencySet, UInt32&
>   pdwNumBuildDependencies, Object& pvarBuildDependencies, String&
>   pbstrFolderUrl, String& pbstrContentTypeOrder, Guid& pgDocScopeId)
>   at
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.Library.SPRequestInternalClass.GetFileAndMetaInfo(String
>   bstrUrl, Byte bPageView, Byte bPageMode, Byte bGetBuildDependencySet,
>   String bstrCurrentFolderUrl, Int32 iRequestVersion, Byte
>   bMainFileRequest, Boolean& pbCanCustomizePages, Boolean&
>   pbCanPersonalizeWebParts, Boolean& pbCanAddDeleteWebParts, Boolean&
>   pbGhostedDocument, Boolean& pbDefaultToPersonal, Boolean&
>   pbIsWebWelcomePage, String& pbstrSiteRoot, Guid& pgSiteId, UInt32&
>   pdwVersion, String& pbstrTimeLastModified, String& pbstrContent,
>   UInt32& pdwPartCount, Object& pvarMetaData, Object&
>   pvarMultipleMeetingDoclibRootFolders, String& pbstrRedirectUrl,
>   Boolean& pbObjectIsList, Guid& pgListId, UInt32& pdwItemId, Int64&
>   pllListFlags, Boolean& pbAccessDenied, Guid& pgDocid, Byte& piLevel,
>   UInt64& ppermMask, Object& pvarBuildDependencySet, UInt32&
>   pdwNumBuildDependencies, Object& pvarBuildDependencies, String&
>   pbstrFolderUrl, String& pbstrContentTypeOrder, Guid& pgDocScopeId)
>   at Microsoft.SharePoint.Library.SPRequest.GetFileAndMetaInfo(String
>   bstrUrl, Byte bPageView, Byte bPageMode, Byte bGetBuildDependencySet,
>   String bstrCurrentFolderUrl, Int32 iRequestVersion, Byte
>   bMainFileRequest, Boolean& pbCanCustomizePages, Boolean&
>   pbCanPersonalizeWebParts, Boolean& pbCanAddDeleteWebParts, Boolean&
>   pbGhostedDocument, Boolean& pbDefaultToPersonal, Boolean&
>   pbIsWebWelcomePage, String& pbstrSiteRoot, Guid& pgSiteId, UInt32&
>   pdwVersion, String& pbstrTimeLastModified, String& pbstrContent,
>   UInt32& pdwPartCount, Object& pvarMetaData, Object&
>   pvarMultipleMeetingDoclibRootFolders, String& pbstrRedirectUrl,
>   Boolean& pbObjectIsList, Guid& pgListId, UInt32& pdwItemId, Int64&
>   pllListFlags, Boolean& pbAccessDenied, Guid& pgDocid, Byte& piLevel,
>   UInt64& ppermMask, Object& pvarBuildDependencySet, UInt32&
>   pdwNumBuildDependencies, Object& pvarBuildDependencies, String&
>   pbstrFolderUrl, String& pbstrContentTypeOrder, Guid& pgDocScopeId)
>   at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPWeb.GetWebPartPageContent(Uri pageUrl, Int32
>   pageVersion, PageView requestedView, HttpContext context, Boolean
>   forRender, Boolean includeHidden, Boolean mainFileRequest, Boolean
>   fetchDependencyInformation, Boolean& ghostedPage, String& siteRoot,
>   Guid& siteId, Int64& bytes, Guid& docId, UInt32& docVersion, String&
>   timeLastModified, Byte& level, Object& buildDependencySetData, UInt32&
>   dependencyCount, Object& buildDependencies,
>   SPWebPartCollectionInitialState& initialState, Object&
>   oMultipleMeetingDoclibRootFolders, String& redirectUrl, Boolean&
>   ObjectIsList, Guid& listId)     at
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.ApplicationRuntime.SPRequestModuleData.FetchWebPartPageInformationForInit(HttpContext
>   context, SPWeb spweb, Boolean mainFileRequest, String path, Boolean
>   impersonate, Boolean& isAppWeb, Boolean& fGhostedPage, Guid& docId,
>   UInt32& docVersion, String& timeLastModified, SPFileLevel& spLevel,
>   String& masterPageUrl, String& customMasterPageUrl, String& webUrl,
>   String& siteUrl, Guid& siteId, Object& buildDependencySetData,
>   SPWebPartCollectionInitialState& initialState, String& siteRoot,
>   String& redirectUrl, Object& oMultipleMeetingDoclibRootFolders,
>   Boolean& objectIsList, Guid& listId, Int64& bytes)     at
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.ApplicationRuntime.SPRequestModuleData.GetFileForRequest(HttpContext
>   context, SPWeb web, Boolean exclusion, String virtualPath)     at
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.ApplicationRuntime.SPRequestModule.InitContextWeb(HttpContext
>   context, SPWeb web)     at
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.WebControls.SPControl.SPWebEnsureSPControl(HttpContext
>   context)     at
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.ApplicationRuntime.SPRequestModule.GetContextWeb(HttpContext
>   context)     at
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.ApplicationRuntime.SPRequestModule.PostResolveRequestCacheHandler(Object
>   oSender, EventArgs ea)     at
>   System.Web.HttpApplication.SyncEventExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute()
>   at System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step,
>   Boolean& completedSynchronously)     at
>   System.Web.HttpApplication.PipelineStepManager.ResumeSteps(Exception
>   error)     at
>   System.Web.HttpApplication.BeginProcessRequestNotification(HttpContext
>   context, AsyncCallback cb)     at
>   System.Web.HttpRuntime.ProcessRequestNotificationPrivate(IIS7WorkerRequest
>   wr, HttpContext context)     at
>   System.Web.Hosting.PipelineRuntime.ProcessRequestNotificationHelper(IntPtr
>   rootedObjectsPointer, IntPtr nativeRequestContext, IntPtr moduleData,
>   Int32 flags)     at
>   System.Web.Hosting.PipelineRuntime.ProcessRequestNotification(IntPtr
>   rootedObjectsPointer, IntPtr nativeRequestContext, IntPtr moduleData,
>   Int32 flags)     at
>   System.Web.Hosting.UnsafeIISMethods.MgdIndicateCompletion(IntPtr
>   pHandler, RequestNotificationStatus& notificationStatus)     at
>   System.Web.Hosting.UnsafeIISMethods.MgdIndicateCompletion(IntPtr
>   pHandler, RequestNotificationStatus& notificationStatus)     at
>   System.Web.Hosting.PipelineRuntime.ProcessRequestNotificationHelper(IntPtr
>   rootedObjectsPointer, IntPtr nativeRequestContext, IntPtr moduleData,
>   Int32 flags)     at
>   System.Web.Hosting.PipelineRuntime.ProcessRequestNotification(IntPtr
>   rootedObjectsPointer, IntPtr nativeRequestContext, IntPtr moduleData,
>   Int32 flags)  2bcc1e9d-888d-80ef-0089-f88bde0ba113 07/29/2015
>   11:12:12.39   w3wp.exe (0x23D4)   0x1F44  SharePoint
>   Foundation    Files   aiv4w   Medium  Spent 0 ms to bind 3356 byte file
>   stream    2bcc1e9d-888d-80ef-0089-f88bde0ba113 07/29/2015
>   11:12:12.39   w3wp.exe (0x23D4)   0x1F44  SharePoint Foundation   Logging
>   Correlation
>   Data  xmnv    Medium  Site=/sites/somesite    2bcc1e9d-888d-80ef-0089-f88bde0ba113
>   07/29/2015 11:12:12.39    w3wp.exe (0x23D4)   0x1F44  SharePoint
>   Foundation    Monitoring  b4ly    High    Leaving Monitored Scope
>   (PostResolveRequestCacheHandler). Execution
>   Time=12.5993666792847 2bcc1e9d-888d-80ef-0089-f88bde0ba113 07/29/2015
>   11:12:12.43   w3wp.exe (0x23D4)   0x1F44  SharePoint
>   Foundation    Monitoring  b4ly    High    Leaving Monitored Scope (Wiki Edit
>   OnInitComplete). Execution
>   Time=19.5008024762924 2bcc1e9d-888d-80ef-0089-f88bde0ba113 07/29/2015
>   11:12:12.48   w3wp.exe (0x23D4)   0x1F44  SharePoint
>   Foundation    Authentication
>   Authorization aib3w   Medium  SPShareByLinkHandler.IsShareableByLink :
>   ShareByLink disabled at SPSite or tenant
>   level 2bcc1e9d-888d-80ef-0089-f88bde0ba113 07/29/2015
>   11:12:12.48   w3wp.exe (0x23D4)   0x1F44  SharePoint
>   Foundation    Authentication
>   Authorization ajp2l   Medium  SPShareByLinkHandler.CanManageSharingLinkForNewDocument
>   : container is not shareable  2bcc1e9d-888d-80ef-0089-f88bde0ba113
>   07/29/2015 11:12:12.50    w3wp.exe (0x23D4)   0x1F44  SharePoint
>   Foundation    Authentication
>   Authorization aib3w   Medium  SPShareByLinkHandler.IsShareableByLink :
>   ShareByLink disabled at SPSite or tenant
>   level 2bcc1e9d-888d-80ef-0089-f88bde0ba113 07/29/2015
>   11:12:12.50   w3wp.exe (0x23D4)   0x1F44  SharePoint
>   Foundation    Authentication
>   Authorization ajp2l   Medium  SPShareByLinkHandler.CanManageSharingLinkForNewDocument
>   : container is not shareable  2bcc1e9d-888d-80ef-0089-f88bde0ba113
>   07/29/2015 11:12:12.51    w3wp.exe (0x23D4)   0x1F44  SharePoint
>   Foundation    Authentication
>   Authorization aib3w   Medium  SPShareByLinkHandler.IsShareableByLink :
>   ShareByLink disabled at SPSite or tenant
>   level 2bcc1e9d-888d-80ef-0089-f88bde0ba113 07/29/2015
>   11:12:12.51   w3wp.exe (0x23D4)   0x1F44  SharePoint
>   Foundation    Authentication
>   Authorization ajp2l   Medium  SPShareByLinkHandler.CanManageSharingLinkForNewDocument
>   : container is not shareable  2bcc1e9d-888d-80ef-0089-f88bde0ba113
>   07/29/2015 11:12:12.51    w3wp.exe (0x23D4)   0x1F44  SharePoint
>   Foundation    Authentication
>   Authorization aib3w   Medium  SPShareByLinkHandler.IsShareableByLink :
>   ShareByLink disabled at SPSite or tenant
>   level 2bcc1e9d-888d-80ef-0089-f88bde0ba113 07/29/2015
>   11:12:12.51   w3wp.exe (0x23D4)   0x1F44  SharePoint
>   Foundation    Authentication
>   Authorization ajp2l   Medium  SPShareByLinkHandler.CanManageSharingLinkForNewDocument
>   : container is not shareable  2bcc1e9d-888d-80ef-0089-f88bde0ba113
>   07/29/2015 11:12:12.56    w3wp.exe (0x23D4)   0x1F44  SharePoint
>   Foundation    Authentication
>   Authorization aib3w   Medium  SPShareByLinkHandler.IsShareableByLink :
>   ShareByLink disabled at SPSite or tenant
>   level 2bcc1e9d-888d-80ef-0089-f88bde0ba113 07/29/2015
>   11:12:12.56   w3wp.exe (0x23D4)   0x1F44  SharePoint
>   Foundation    Authentication
>   Authorization ajp2l   Medium  SPShareByLinkHandler.CanManageSharingLinkForNewDocument
>   : container is not shareable  2bcc1e9d-888d-80ef-0089-f88bde0ba113
>   07/29/2015 11:14:13.96    w3wp.exe (0x23D4)   0x1F44  SharePoint
>   Foundation    Upgrade aiaih   High    [Forced due to logging gap, cached @
>   07/29/2015 11:12:12.56, Original Level: Verbose] desiredVersion:
>   {0}   2bcc1e9d-888d-80ef-0089-f88bde0ba113 07/29/2015
>   11:14:13.96   w3wp.exe (0x23D4)   0x1F44  SharePoint
>   Foundation    Monitoring  b4ly    High    Leaving Monitored Scope (Wiki Edit
>   OnPreRenderComplete). Execution
>   Time=121377.751641619 2bcc1e9d-888d-80ef-0089-f88bde0ba113 07/29/2015
>   11:14:13.96   w3wp.exe (0x23D4)   0x1F44  SharePoint
>   Foundation    General 8nca    Medium  Application error when access
>   /sites/somesite/SitePages/Home.aspx, Error=Request timed
>   out.  2bcc1e9d-888d-80ef-0089-f88bde0ba113 07/29/2015
>   11:14:13.96   w3wp.exe (0x23D4)   0x1F44  SharePoint
>   Foundation    Runtime tkau    Unexpected  System.Web.HttpException: Request
>   timed out.    2bcc1e9d-888d-80ef-0089-f88bde0ba113 07/29/2015
>   11:14:13.96   w3wp.exe (0x23D4)   0x1F44  SharePoint
>   Foundation    General ajlz0   High    Getting Error Message for Exception
>   System.Web.HttpException (0x80004005): Request timed
>   out.  2bcc1e9d-888d-80ef-0089-f88bde0ba113 07/29/2015
>   11:14:13.96   w3wp.exe (0x23D4)   0x1F44  SharePoint
>   Foundation    General aat87   Monitorable     2bcc1e9d-888d-80ef-0089-f88bde0ba113
>   07/29/2015 11:14:13.96    w3wp.exe (0x23D4)   0x1F44  SharePoint
>   Foundation    Micro Trace uls4    Medium  Micro Trace Tags: 0 nasq,7 agb9s,9
>   ak8dj,3 b4ly,37 b4ly,49 aib3w,0 ajp2l,16 aib3w,0 ajp2l,11 aib3w,0
>   ajp2l,10 aib3w,0 ajp2l,39 aib3w,0 ajp2l,121387 b4ly,2 8nca,0 tkau,0
>   ajlz0,0 aat87 2bcc1e9d-888d-80ef-0089-f88bde0ba113 07/29/2015
>   11:14:13.96   w3wp.exe (0x23D4)   0x1F44  SharePoint
>   Foundation    Monitoring  b4ly    Medium  Leaving Monitored Scope (Request
>   (GET:http://mywebapp.com/sites/somesite/SitePages/Home.aspx)).
>   Execution Time=121581.941280247   2bcc1e9d-888d-80ef-0089-f88bde0ba113

Comment: did you runt he psconfig wizard....can u check the Central admin and status of the Content Databases...should be no action required.

Comment: I did. Upgrade status succeeded, with all content databases requiring no action. Interestingly, the BDC database states "Database is in compatibility range and upgrade is recommended", but we aren't using the BDC anywhere in the farm.